# How to insert class in HTML tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is my question :

**How to insert class in HTML tag using CSS? Not using JavaScript/JQuery, I know how to do using scripts. So please don't answer any if you are trying to answer it using scripts.**

Here is my simple code:

```
<a href="" class="close">Close</a>
```

I want to insert a class name "modal" into this tag but using CSS. Is there any possibility? I knew about using "content" in CSS, but nothing to do with content; but here I'm talking inserting class like scripts but not with scripts.

I knew this is something called **"CRAZY"** but what about solution, anybody have or tried.

Comment: It is not possible by pure css.

Comment: Not possible with just CSS. Maybe you can combine the properties of the other class into the already existing one. But that is not logical.

Answer (score 3):

The options you have are:

- Injecting the class with JavaScript (or JavaScript libraries like jQuery)
- Having a server (or local server using XAMPP or similar tools ) that runs PHP / Python / something similar to render your page and fill in the class in a template

**There is no way of doing this with pure CSS.**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add classes via css. CSS is just not made for purpose to modify DOM, CSS works with existent DOM. CSS is used to style a document and to enhance its design aspects.

You would be able to do so by either:

```
<a href="" class="close modal">Close</a>
```

or via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is impossible. The CSS can not change the structures of the `DOM`.

But, if there are more than one tag with the class `close` you can try to get a particular tag by `nth-child()`.

If you tell us what really you want to do, perhaps we can try another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It’s impossible.

You can’t do this with css.

Because CSS didn’t design for this.

You can only do this.

```
<tagname class="class-name"> ... </tagname>
```